# Exchange Server 2016 on Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016

I am trying to install Exchange Server 2016 on Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4 for test purposes. The installation process stops because Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra component is missing. Install-WindowsFeature PowerShell cmdlet fails to install this feature ("ArgumentNotValid: The role, role service, or feature name is not valid"). Similarly, I cannot find "User Interfaces and Infrastructure" features in Windows Add Roles and Features Wizard. It appears that this feature is simply not available in Win2016 TP4 or is named differently. Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: See supported operating systems at:  https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa996719%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste your time with this combination, it doesn't work.

It will need a future version of Exchange as well as the released version of Windows 2016 Server. Considering the time frame for Windows 2016 Server, I expect it will be CU2 or CU3 for Exchange 2016 before the combination works.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install Exchange on an unsupported preview release of Windows. What were you expecting, exactly?

Wait for the final release of WS2016, and for Microsoft to support installing Exchange on it.

Comment: I know it is not officially supported, hard to expect Exchange Server to support Technical Preview release of Windows. Let me give you some background: I work for an independent MS Exchange software vendor and we want to perform preliminary tests with new Windows prior to its official release so we can address any problems in our software before Windows 2016 goes to the market. Otherwise, the official premiere day our customer support gets hammered with complaints we do not know if the software works with the new Windows.

Comment: I understand your need for this kind of testing; but you can't really expect anyone to help you if (when) something doesn't work on a new, beta and unsupported platform. Not here, anyway; try asking on Microsoft forums.