# Install Exchange 2016 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, exchange, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

As the title suggests I am trying to install Exchange 2016 on Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition. In unattended mode, to be specific.

The installation fails with the same error as in [Exchange Server 2016 on Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4](https://serverfault.com/questions/745556/exchange-server-2016-on-windows-server-2016-technical-preview-4), namely that the component *Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra* is missing, even though 1) it doesn't exist and 2) I have a GUI installed on the server (not Core).

It seems that the issue with TP4 and TP5 still persists in the final release.

Has anyone else had any success with this combination? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719(v=exchg.160).aspx), Exchange Server 2016 is supported on Windows Server 2016, but **only when using CU3 or later**.

You are probably trying to install an earlier Exchange release, which doesn't support WS2016; you can check and download the latest version [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj907309(v=exchg.160).aspx).

Exchange CUs are full installers, thus you don't need to install the RTM version and then apply an update; you can (and should) perform your Exchange installation using the latest available CU (currently CU3, which also adds support for Windows Server 2016).

Comment: Additional to that microsoft posted the following that Exchange 2016 might crash on Windows 2016 without hotfix which is about to be released: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/11/04/update-on-windows-server-2016-and-exchange-server-2016/